# How to ensure constraint that keys should be one of the items in some user defined array

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I am using JSON for defining some configuration files and I want to validate them with [json scheme](http://json-schema.org/). My problem is that I want to ensure that keys of some object should be subset of items of an array defined in same JSON:
ex:

Valid:

```
{
      "files": ["file1", "file2"],
      "filelocations": {
           "file1": "/etc/globalconfigs/file1.conf",
           "file2": "/usr/bin/file2.sh"
      }
}
```

Invalid (otherkey is not in `files`):

```
{
      "files": ["file1", "file2"],
      "filelocations": {
           "file1": "/etc/globalconfigs/file1.conf",
           "otherkey": "/usr/bin/file2.sh"
      }
}
```

etc. What I want is to ensure that keys of `filelocations` are found in `files` array.
Although in this example, we can change the structure of JSON by combining keys-values so that there is no need to have this kind of constraint, in my case I can't change JSON like this, so it is nice to have a validation mechanism for this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with JSON Schema, there are no combination of keywords which can guarantee this.

If you are adventurous (and I can even code that for you), you can use [my JSON Schema API](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) and code a custom keyword to fit your needs, however. It is doable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you think that my requirement is a valid and common problem for people that are / will using JSON and its schema? If that's the case, adding a custom keyword to achieve this might be good idea so that specification become more mature. Otherwise, it might not worth it because I can check this requirement in code using the JSON.

Comment: I don't think it is a very common requirement to be honest. Especially since the JSON can here be refactored so that there need not be a separated array mentioning the keys.

Comment: I also thought that this may not be a common requirement and you are right, I can refactor JSON but in current form it makes things a lot easier for me and for people using it. So I will continue like this and do the check in my code using JSON. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to have a look at jsonary: it uses hyperschema to great effect. In short, hyperschema can also help you _produce_ JSON, and this is also written in the schema itself.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at jsonary, it seems interesting.